# aws - How to add multiple postgresql connectors to EMR via configuration file

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

To add **one** postgresql connector to presto in AWS EMR, can be achieved with the config file below.

```
[
    {
        "Classification": "presto-connector-postgresql",
        "Properties": {
            "connection-url": "jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>",
            "connection-user": "<user>",
            "connection-password": "<password>"
        },
        "Configurations": []
    }
]
```

However, when I attempted to simply add an item to the config file, like so:

```
[
    {
        "Classification": "presto-connector-postgresql",
        "Properties": {
            "connection-url": "jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>",
            "connection-user": "<user>",
            "connection-password": "<password>"
        },
        "Configurations": []
    },
    {
        "Classification": "presto-connector-postgresql",
        "Properties": {
            "connection-url": "jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<another-database>",
            "connection-user": "<user>",
            "connection-password": "<password>"
        },
        "Configurations": []
    }

]
```

Terraform complains: `Classification 'presto-connector-postgresql' was specified multiple times.`

This can be achieved by manually adding each database in a database.properties file under /etc/presto/conf/catalog folder.

database.properties

```
connector.name=postgresql
connection-password = <password>
connection-url = jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>
connection-user = <user>
```

another-database.properties

```
connector.name=postgresql
connection-password = <password>
connection-url = jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<another-database>
connection-user = <user>
```

Just wondering if there is a way to achieve the same goal via the EMR configuration.

Comment: I am having the same scenario. Is there any updates on this?

Comment: Im having the same problem, and went for the workaround of adding a new file to `/etc/catalog` as described [here](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/connector/postgresql.html). It would be good for AWS to solve it